# How to output a PHP array from ajax $_POST and split or explode the values into key and value

Tags: php, ajax, variables, explode

I am attempting to take array values sent via $_POST from ajax and use the delimitator as the point to split/explode into a usable variable.

Sample of ajax:

```
function update_dt_reason() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "inc/daily.update.dt_reason.php?",
        type: "post",
        data: $('.dt_reasons:checked').serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#txtNew').html(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Example of PHP:

```
<?php
$testing = print_r($_POST);
$array = array();
$array = explode('|', $testing);
foreach($array as $key => $testing)
{
    $array[$key] = explode('|', $testing);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Example Output Array:

```
Array (
[Well] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1|5
        [1] => 1|3
        [2] => 1|1
        [3] => 1|6
        [4] => 1|7
        [5] => 1|2
        [6] => 1|4
        [7] => 2|1
        [8] => 2|6
        [9] => 2|7
        [10] => 2|4
        [11] => 3|5
        [12] => 3|1
    ))
```

Desired output:
Either of the below two:

```
Array ([0] => 1 => 5)
Array ([1] => 1 => 3)
Array ([2] => 1 => 1) etc.
```

Or, which would be even better:

```
Array
(
[0] => 1 => Array 
   (
      [0]=>5
      [1]=>3
      [2]=>1
      [3]=>6
      [4]=>7
      [5]=>2
      ...
   )
[1] => 2 => Array 
   (
      [0]=>1
      [1]=>6
      [2]=>1
      [3]=>7
      [4]=>4
   )
[2] => 3 => Array 
   (
      [0]=>5
      [1]=>1
   )
```

I can't submit without more information, so I will try to have more, while keeping it relevant.
I am using a form with multiple checkboxes that are assigned to ID's in a sql database. They are all listed, and are tied back to the record that will be updated by the check/uncheck of the box.
I'm attempting to add a picture for a visual reference.
[image: Visual of the form and array]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your PHP script. Try this:

```
<?php
$testing = print_r($_POST);
$array = array();
// $array = explode('|', $testing);         // Remove this line
foreach($_POST['Well'] as $key => $testing)   // Loop over the POSTed array
{
    $array[$key] = explode('|', $testing);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);                             // Print the result, not the input.
?>
```

Here's a version that produces your preferred format:

```
<?php
$_POST['Well']=[0=>"1|2", 1=>'3|4', 2=>'1|5'];
$arr = [];
foreach($_POST['Well'] as $val) {
    $t = explode("|",$val);
    if (!isset($arr, $t[0])) {
        $arr[$t[0]] = [];
    }
    $arr[$t[0]][] = $t[1];
}
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you @tangentially-perpendicular. The output is as shown below now: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 6
        )`